# How to get named json response Flutter using http get method

Tags: flutter, dart

ok here is my json format

```
{ 
  "success":true,
  "user":{
           "name":"example"
           "email:"example@email.com"
         }
}
```

ok by using Chopper Flutter it was easy just to get the user object by calling

```
response.body["user"]
```

however the current Chopper version ie the null safety is not stable...so how do you call this method in HTTP? to get the user object only...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse('enterYourUrlHere');
Map<String, dynamic> body = jsonDecode(response.body);
var user = body['user'];
print(user['email']); // prints out example@email.com"
```